# Paging by cells in a vertically scrolling UICollectionView when using custom sectionInset values

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a vertically scrolling `UICollectionView` with paging enabled that uses a subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

My `UICollectionView` is `320x504` and my `UICollectionViewCells` are `287x490`.

I add a `UIImageView` as a subview to my `UICollectionView` and to keep it from covering part of the very first cell, I use the following `sectionInset` values which I set on the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`:

```
self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(130, 0, 100, 0);
```

Here are all the custom settings I'm using for the layout:

```
self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10;
self.minimumLineSpacing = 30;
self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(287, 490);
self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(130, 0, 100, 0);
```

My problem is that when I try to use paging, it works, but it shows 2 cells at a time. It basically shows almost half of the previous cell, and then 80% of the next cell.

This is because of top inset value of `130` that I'm using. If I change that to `0` instead, the paging works much better when scrolling/paging.

How can I still use paging in a vertically scrolling `UICollectionView` and have perfect cell by cell paging when using these custom sectionInset values?

There are a ton of questions on here about this but they all focus on horizontal scrolling, not vertical scrolling.

Comment: hey , found solution ?

Comment: hey,Any Solution?